Grails 6.2.x database integration tests without testcontainer
On my previous projects I used grails 4.x and created integration tests with database access using spock.
Now I am starting a new project with Grails 6.2.0 and it seems to require testcontainers for any integration tests.
My integration tests need to access an old MS SQL server with an existing database (in read only mode) to do some data processing and migration.
In build.gradle I have removed any dependencies to org.testcontaners:... but am still getting the following exception when trying to run the integration tests:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver


So my question is: Is there a way to configure grails 6.2.x to not use testcontainers for integration tests or am I forced to use it?
